# Allocate values for each user in Performance Center

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, hp-performance-center

I have created a script in VuGen which has a parameter that is a dat file.

For that parameter I have specified how many values should be allocated to each user under Allocate Vuser values in the controller.

Now when I upload my scripts to Performance Center I can specify how many Vuser I need but I can't modify the Allocated Vusers value.

I don't understand the concept... I can update the Vusers without uploading the script again but I can't update how many values will each Vuser get during the execution without modifying the scripts and re-uploading them.

Am I missing something...

Answer (score 0):

I check the online help for "Allocate Vuser values in the Controller" option, it's noted with "(LoadRunner only)", so that it is missing from PC (LR Enterprise).